# db:migrate (PostgreSQL) fails on Rails deployment with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, web-deployment

I'm a complete noob to deploying Rails and even more new to PostgreSQL.  I'm running a CentOS 6.6 server and my deployment tasks keep failing with the following db:migrate errors:

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: /var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:42: warning: duplicated key at line 80 ignored: "name"
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "me", database "pg_sampleapp", SSL off
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:913:in `initialize'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `new'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:16:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: /var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:42: warning: duplicated key at line 80 ignored: "name"
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "me", database "pg_sampleapp", SSL off
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:913:in `initialize'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `new'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:95:in `exit_status='
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `block in _execute'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `tap'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `_execute'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:16:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `with'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:77:in `within'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-rails-1.1.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/migrations.rake:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:migrate
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: /var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:42: warning: duplicated key at line 80 ignored: "name"
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "me", database "pg_sampleapp", SSL off
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:913:in `initialize'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `new'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/var/www/rally_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
[me@localhost rally_app]$
```

Thanks for any help.

Alexis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user "me" does not have permissions to connect to your database. Permissions are defined in Postgres' `pg_hba.conf`. I haven't used CentOS, but from what I can gather, you should be able to find that file at `/var/lib/pgsql/<your Postgres version>/data`.

Open the config file in your text editor (you might need to run it with `sudo` in order to have permission to edit it), then scroll to the end.

Adding this line:

```
host    pg_sampleapp             me             ::1/128                 password
```

gives your user `me` the permission to access the database `pg_sampleapp` after providing the correct password — but only from localhost, meaning from within your server itself and not when connecting to it from the outside.

You can make the permissions more broad by replacing `pg_sampleapp` and `me` with `all`, meaning that locally all Postgres users can connect to all databases. If you want extra convenience and are not worried about security, you can also replace `password` with `trust`, meaning you can connect directly without providing any password:

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

After adding the permissions, you need to reload Postgres via `service postgresql-9.4 restart` (if you have Postgres 9.4 installed, otherwise change the version accordingly).

You can test whether it works correctly by trying to log into the database with `psql pg_sampleapp me`. If it does, quit psql with CTRL+D.

See the [Postgres documentation on pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for more information — it's quite readable and very detailed.